# Backtracking para sudokus sem solução

Tags: c++, estrutura-de-dados

Meu algoritmo consegue resolver sudokus com solução (não otimizado) mas quando o sudoku não tem solução o algoritmo não atinge a condição de parada.

*Sudoku.hpp*

```
#ifndef _SUDOKU_H_
#define _SUDOKU_H_
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>  // Para uint8_t em alguns compiladores

/// Classe que representa uma possivel jogada (coordenadas e valor)
/// Significado dos valores:
/*
 \ i | i de 0-8 | i<0 | i>8 e j>=0 |
  \j |    e     | ou  |     ou     |
 v \ | j de 0-8 | j<0 | j>8 e i>=0 |
-----+----------+-----+------------+
1 a 9|   JOGAR  | FIM |  RESOLVER  |
  0  |  APAGAR  | FIM | PREENCHER  |
 > 9 |   NOVO   | FIM |   VOLTAR   |
 < 0 |    FIM   | FIM |     FIM    |
*/

class Jogada
{
protected:
  int i,j,v;
public:
  /// Construtor (por default, cria Jogada que termina o jogo)
  Jogada(int I=-1, int J=-1, int V=-1);

  /// Funcoes de acesso
  inline int linha() const {return i;}
  inline int coluna() const {return j;}
  inline int valor() const {return v;}

  /// Testa se a jogada indica que uma casa deve ser preenchida
  inline bool jogada() const {return (i>=0 && i<=8 && j>=0 && j<=8 && v>=1 && v<=9);}

  /// Testa se a jogada indica que uma casa deve ser apagada
  inline bool apagamento() const {return (i>=0 && i<=8 && j>=0 && j<=8 && v==0);}

  /// Testa se a jogada indica que o uruario quer resolver o jogo automaticamente
  inline bool resolver_jogo() const {return ( ((i>8 && j>=0) || (i>=0 && j>8)) && v>=1 && v<=9 );}

  /// Testa se a jogada indica que o uruario quer preencher as casas faceis
  inline bool preencher_jogo() const {return ( ((i>8 && j>=0) || (i>=0 && j>8)) && v==0 );}

  /// Testa se a jogada indica que o uruario quer comecar um novo jogo
  inline bool novo() const {return (i>=0 && i<=8 && j>=0 && j<=8 && v>9);}

  /// Testa se a jogada indica que o uruario quer recomecar (voltar ao tab inicial)
  inline bool voltar() const {return (((i>8 && j>=0) || (i>=0 && j>8)) && v>9);}

  /// Testa se a jogada indica que o uruario quer encerrar o jogo
  inline bool fim_de_jogo() const {return (i<0 || j<0 || v<0);}

  /// Fixa as coordenadas de uma jogada
  void setCell(int I, int J);

  /// Fixa o valor de uma jogada
  void setValue(int V);

  /// O METODO A SEGUIR ENVOLVE FORMATACAO.
  /// O codigo deve ser diferente de acordo com o modo de exibicao

  /// Leh uma jogada do teclado
  void ler();

  friend class Sudoku;
};

class Sudoku
{
private:
  /// "Matriz 9x9" que contem os valores das casas do tabuleiro.
  /// Na realidade, a "matriz 9x9" eh um vector de 81 bytes sem sinal (uint8_t)
  /// O acesso aos elementos da "matriz" se dah atraves dos metodos "set" e "at",
  /// que transformam os indices linha e coluna da matriz no indice do vetor
  /// Conteudo da "matriz":
  /// 1 a 9 - Casa preenchida
  /// 0 - Casa vazia
  std::vector<uint8_t> tab;

  /// Funcao set de alteracao de valor
  /// Retorna uma referencia ao i-j-esimo elemento do tabuleiro
  inline uint8_t& set(unsigned i, unsigned j) {return tab.at(9*i+j);}

  /// Calcula o numero de possibilidades para preencher a casa (i,j)
  /// utilizando apenas as regras "faceis" (linha, coluna e bloco)
  /// Se houver uma unica possibilidade de preenchimento, retorna o valor (1 a 9)
  /// Se nao houver nenhuma possibilidade de preenchimento, retorna 0, o que
  /// indica que o tabuleiro nao tem solucao
  /// Se houver mais de uma possibilidade de preenchimento, retorna um numero
  /// negativo (<0), cujo modulo eh o numero de possibilidades
  int numero_possibilidades(unsigned i, unsigned j) const;
public:
  /// Limpa o tabuleiro
  void limpar();

  /// Gera um novo tabuleiro aleatorio
  void gerar();

  /// Cria um tabuleiro vazio
  inline Sudoku(): tab(81) {limpar();}

  /// Cria um tabuleiro com o conteudo do arquivo nome_arq
  /// Caso nao consiga ler do arquivo, retorna tabuleiro gerado
  /// automaticamente (caso erro ocorra logo no inicio da funcao
  /// de leitura) ou lido parcialmente, caso contrario
  Sudoku(const char *nome_arq);

  /// Destrutor
  inline virtual ~Sudoku() {}

  /// Funcao de consulta
  /// Retorna o i-j-esimo elemento do tabuleiro
  inline uint8_t at(unsigned i, unsigned j) const {return tab.at(9*i+j);}

  /// Operador() de consulta - usa o metodo "at"
  /// Retorna o i-j-esimo elemento do tabuleiro
  inline uint8_t operator()(unsigned i, unsigned j) const {return at(i,j);}

  /// Compara se dois tabuleiros sao iguais
  bool operator==(const Sudoku &S) const;

  /// Testa se a jogada J eh possivel para o tabuleiro
  bool jogada_valida(Jogada J) const;

  /// Testa se a jogada J eh um apagamento valido de uma casa para o tabuleiro,
  /// levando em conta o tabuleiro original (nao eh permitido apagar casas que
  /// estavam preenchidas no tabuleiro original)
  bool apagamento_valido(Jogada J, const Sudoku &Origem) const;

  /// Executa uma jogada (altera o tabuleiro)
  inline void fazer_jogada(Jogada J) {if (jogada_valida(J)) set(J.i,J.j) = J.v;}

  /// Apaga uma casa (altera o tabuleiro)
  inline void apagar_jogada(Jogada J, const Sudoku &O) {if (apagamento_valido(J,O)) set(J.i,J.j) = J.v;}

  /// Testa se o tabuleiro estah completo (fim de jogo)
  bool fim_de_jogo() const;

  /// Retorna o numero de casas vazias no tabuleiro
  unsigned num_casas_vazias() const;

  /// OS 3 METODOS A SEGUIR ENVOLVEM FORMATACAO.
  /// O codigo deve ser diferente de acordo com o modo de exibicao
  /// Por isso as funcoes sao virtuais

  /// Exibir o conteudo do tabuleiro (*this) na posicao de visualizacao do tabuleiro atual
  virtual void exibir() const;

  /// Exibir o conteudo do tabuleiro (*this) na posicao de visualizacao do tabuleiro inicial
  virtual void exibir_origem() const;

  /// Exibe os numeros de tabuleiros gerados, testados e a analisar
  virtual void exibir_andamento(unsigned Ntab_testados, unsigned Ntab_gerados, unsigned Ntab_analisar) const;

  /// Preenche todas as casas "faceis" do tabuleiro, ou seja, aquelas que tem um
  /// unico valor possivel pelas regras do Sudoku
  /// Retorna o numero de casas adicionais preenhidas (0 ou >0) ou entao
  /// retorna <0 se houver alguma casa sem possibilidade de jogada (tabuleiro insoluvel)
  /// Quando retorna um valor negativo (ou seja, o tabuleiro eh insoluvel), o numero
  /// retornado serah o negativo do numero de casas preenchidas. Caso nenhuma casa
  /// tenha sido preeenchida e o tabuleiro seja insoluvel, serah retornado um numero
  /// negativo menor que -81.
  int resolver_casas_faceis();

  /// Determina automaticamente a solucao do tabuleiro (preenche as casas vazias).
  ///
  /// O parametro com_exibicao controla se o algoritmo deve (true) ou nao (false)
  /// exibir os tabuleiros analisados e o numero de nohs durante o algoritmo.
  ///
  /// O parametro "basta_primeira_solucao" fixa se o algoritmo deve (true) ou nao (false)
  /// retornar assim que encontrar a primeira solucao, sem verificar se existe outra.
  ///
  /// Retorna 0 se nao foi encontrada solucao, 1 se foi encontrada uma solucao unica
  /// e >1 se existem mais de uma solucao (essa ultima possibilidade de retorno soh
  /// existe se o parametro basta_primeira_solucao for false.
  ///
  int resolver(bool com_exibicao=true, bool basta_primeira_solucao=true);

};

#endif // _SUDOKU_H_
```

*Sudoku.cpp*

```
int Sudoku::resolver(bool com_exibicao, bool basta_primeira_solucao) {

    // Contadores do numero de tabuleiros gerados e testados
    int num_tab_gerados(1), num_tab_testados(1);

    // Testa se jah nao estah resolvido desde o inicio
    if (this->fim_de_jogo()) {
        cout << "Ja esta resolvido!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Tab. solucao
    Sudoku sol;
    // Fila com os tabuleiros.
    queue<Sudoku> Aberto;
    Aberto.push(*this);

    bool encontrou_solucao = false;

    int i, j, k;

    do {
        // Extrai tabuleiro da fila.
        sol = Aberto.front();
        Aberto.pop();
        num_tab_testados++;

        if (sol.fim_de_jogo()) {
            encontrou_solucao = true;
        } else {
            // Escolhe a primeira casa vaga
            i = 0;
            j = 0;
            while (i < 9 && sol(i, j) != 0) {
                j++;
                if (j >= 9) {
                    j = 0;
                    i++;
                }
            }

            // Testa jogadas possiveis em sol(i,j)
            // Escolhe o primeiro valor de jogada para a casa.
            // Se soh houver um valor possivel joga esse valor.
            Jogada J(i, j);

            // Calcula a(s) possibilidades de jogada na casa (i,j)
            k = sol.numero_possibilidades(i, j);
            if (k == 0) {
                // Tabuleiro S nao tem solucao
                J.setValue(-1); // Jogada invalida
                break;          // Sai do laço pois o tabuleiro nao tem solucao
            } else if (k < 0) {
                // Existe mais de uma possibilidade de jogada
                // Verifica os valores possiveis para jogada e cria tab. sucessores (1~9).
                for (int z = 1; z < 10; z++) {
                    J.setValue(z);
                    // Se a jogada for valida gera novo tabuleiro: sucessor
                    // de tab com a jogada.
                    if (sol.jogada_valida(J)) {
                        Sudoku suc = sol;
                        suc.fazer_jogada(J);
                        Aberto.push(suc);
                        num_tab_gerados++;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Soh existe uma possibilidade de jogada
                J.setValue(k);
                // Se a jogada for valida gera novo tabuleiro: sucessor
                // de tab com a jogada.
                if (sol.jogada_valida(J)) {
                    Sudoku suc = sol;
                    suc.fazer_jogada(J);
                    Aberto.push(suc);
                    num_tab_gerados++;
                }
            }
        }

        if (com_exibicao /*&& (num_tab_testados % 10000 == 0)*/) {
            sol.exibir();
            exibir_andamento(num_tab_testados, num_tab_gerados, Aberto.size());
            //cout << "Ignorados: " << num_tab_ignorados << endl;
        }
        //cout << num_tab_gerados << endl;

    } while ((!encontrou_solucao && !Aberto.empty()) && num_tab_testados < 1000000);

    // Pode ter terminado porque
    // encontrou a solução ou porque
    // não há mais tabuleiros a testar
    if (!encontrou_solucao) {
        cout << "Sudoku sem solucao!" << endl;
        exibir_andamento(num_tab_testados, num_tab_gerados, Aberto.size());
        return 0;
    } else {
        cout << "Solucao:" << endl;
        if (com_exibicao) {
            sol.exibir();
        }
        exibir_andamento(num_tab_testados, num_tab_gerados, Aberto.size());
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Quando o sudoku não tem solução ele continua gerando nos infinitamente. **Eu não consigo entender o porquê disso.**

*obs: Limitei o nr. de iterações porque ele iterage infinitamente para esse tipo de tabuleiro de sudoku (sem solução). Uma vez que eu consiga entender o porquê ele está com esse comportamente indesejado essa condição será removida.*

A pedido de [v.santos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/142154/v-santos) segue o código da função *numero_de_possibilidades*:

```cpp
/// Calcula o numero de possibilidades para preencher a casa (i,j)
/// utilizando apenas as regras "faceis" (linha, coluna e bloco)
/// Se houver uma unica possibilidade de preenchimento, retorna o valor (1 a 9)
/// Se nao houver nenhuma possibilidade de preenchimento, retorna 0, o que
/// indica que o tabuleiro nao tem solucao
/// Se houver mais de uma possibilidade de preenchimento, retorna um numero
/// negativo (<= -2), cujo modulo eh o numero de possibilidades
int Sudoku::numero_possibilidades(unsigned i, unsigned j) const {
    // A principio, todos os 9 valores de jogada sao possiveis
    bool valor_possivel[] = {true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true};
    unsigned ii, I, jj, J, k;

    // Se a casa jah estiver preenchida, nao hah nenhuma possibilidade
    if (at(i, j) != 0)
        return -1;

    // Varre a linha
    for (k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
        if (at(i, k) > 0)
            valor_possivel[at(i, k) - 1] = false;
    }

    // Varre a coluna
    for (k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
        if (at(k, j) > 0)
            valor_possivel[at(k, j) - 1] = false;
    }

    // Varre a quadra
    I = 3 * (i / 3);
    J = 3 * (j / 3);
    for (ii = 0; ii < 3; ii++)
        for (jj = 0; jj < 3; jj++) {
            if (at(I + ii, J + jj) > 0)
                valor_possivel[at(I + ii, J + jj) - 1] = false;
        }

    // Conta o numero de valores possiveis
    unsigned num_possiveis = 0;
    for (k = 0; k < 9; k++) {
        if (valor_possivel[k])
            num_possiveis++;
    }

    // Nao hah nenhum valor possivel
    if (num_possiveis == 0)
        return 0;

    // Hah mais de um valor possivel
    if (num_possiveis > 1)
        return -num_possiveis;

    // Hah uma unica possibilidade de preenchimento da casa
    // Retorna o valor possivel
    k = 0;
    while (!valor_possivel[k])
        k++;
    return k + 1;
}
```

Comment: Em um primeiro momento, eu apostaria que o bug está no método  `Sudoku::numero_possibilidades()`. Você chegou a verificar isso?

Comment: Sim, vou adicionar o código da função a publicação principal.

Comment: Acho que o problema é de lógica, por algum motivo, quando o Sudoku não tem solução ele  gera nós infinitamente. Em teoria, quando uma casa do tabuleiro não tem possibilidade de jogada ele descarta o tabuleiro e todo o ramo é descartado por conseguinte, passando a analisar o próximo daquele nível.